# How can I create an array of directory contents in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays

I need to make 3 arrays from the contents of `$directory`.
The first one I can use:

```
$var = qx{ls $directory};
print $var;
```

However the second and third I want to grep for "Primary *" and "Secondary *"

I've used the commands:

```
my @primary = 0;
my @secondary = 0;

@primary = system("ls test_77 > test | grep Primary* test");
print @primary;
@secondary = system("ls test_77 > test | grep Secondary* test");
print @secondary;
```

BUT, it includes a zero on the output:

```
PrimaryCPE_Option_A.txt.test_77
PrimaryCPE_Option_B.txt.test_77
0SecondaryCPE_Option_A.txt.test_77
SecondaryCPE_Option_B.txt.test_77
0
```

What can it be?  At first it looks like it might be the original zero, but I can change the initial value of either and it doesn't work.

Comment: Avoid 'system' while using Perl, whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl can do this without calling system commands.

```
@secondary=glob("*Secondary*.txt");
print @secondary;
@primary=glob("*Primary*.txt")
print @primary;
```

Other ways are using opendir()/readdir(), or while loop eg

```
while(my $file=<*Primary*txt>){
  push(@secondary,$file);
}
```

Or

```
push (@secondary,$_) while<*Secondary*.txt> ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to everone, this is working perfectly.
You are all brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

The following will read all the files in the current directory,
and store them into one array.  It excludes sub-directories, but it does include
files which start with the `.` character.  Then, it creates the 2 other arrays from the 1st array. Refer to [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp/lib/File/Slurp.pm).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw(read_dir);

my @all_files = grep { -f $_ } read_dir('./');
my @pfiles = grep {/^Primary/  } @all_files;
my @sfiles = grep {/^Secondary/} @all_files;
```

I'll try to address your questions now.
`system` returns the exit status of the external command (`ls`, for example).  It does not return the directory listing.  You would use `qx` to return the directory listing.  Refer to [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

So, since your `ls` command succeeds, its exit status is 0.  Thus, `system` returns 0. This value is stored into the 1st element of your array.  That is the only value in your array.  Any other output you see is coming from your `grep`, I believe.

Also, the only way I come close to reproducing your output is to change the pipe to a semicolon in your `system` call, and by getting rid of `*`:

```
@primary = system("ls test_77 > test ; grep Primary test");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would write this program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;  # this is so that you don't have to check opendir(), and readdir().

my @files = grep {
  -f $_;
} do{
  opendir my $dir, '.';
  readdir $dir;
};

my @primary   = grep {/Primary/  } @files;
my @secondary = grep {/Secondary/} @files;
```

---

You are putting the 0 on the list by declaring the arrays like this:

```
my @primary = 0;
```

If you want an empty array, you just declare it.

```
my @primary;
```

If you want to explicitly set an array to nothing:

```
@primary = ();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) (and `readdir`, etc.).

At the moment you're spawning off new processes and piping them together, whereas Perl can do all of this in process using standard built-in commands. The results will come back immediately as an array for further processing using Perl regular expressions.

(Note that you need to escape the `*` in your `grep` if you continue with your approach.)