# What are the comparative advantages of glob('foo*') over <foo*>?

Tags: perl, glob

I was just looking at [Can someone tell me how to create an array of directory contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087850/can-someone-tell-me-how-to-create-an-array-of-directory-contents-perl).  Unsurprisingly, file globs were offered as an answer.  What surprised me was that the post recommended using [`glob()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) rather than [`<*>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators).

I use `<*>` because that is what I learned a long time ago and have never thought about it.  Which is not a good reason.

What syntax do you prefer for globbing, and why?

Comment: I'm curious about why you made this community wiki. It's a good question, on-topic, and not very subjective. Marking it CW takes away some of the incentive for people interested in building their reputations to answer. Did you want to lower the bar for others to edit the question itself?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I wouldn't have minded the rep, either.  I made it CW because the question is subjective and is poll-like.  What do *you* prefer? Rather than a question with a single correct answer.  My understanding is that these kind of questions should be CW.  I could be wrong, I have been, countless times on many subjects.

Comment: A single correct answer? In Perl?!?!!? TMTOWTDI! (-:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally, I think that `<>` is badly overloaded. It sort of means "read from an iterator" but there's a little too much magic and subtlety in determining which iterator of what kind for my taste. e.g. `<$foo>` and `<$foo{bar}>` mean very different things, and the magical bare `<>` means something different yet.

I prefer to use `glob` and reserve the `<>` syntax for handles. Doing that saves the cognitive burden of figuring out whether the contents of the `<>` is a pattern rather than a handle (or something that resolves to one). That said, if you mentally associate the `<>` notation with "iterator" instead of "read" you might prefer that to the functional syntax -- at least for those cases where you want to step over the results rather than generate a list.

Answer (score 10):

That perldoc you linked says there's some issues with the angle-bracket syntax:

> One level of double-quote
>   interpretation is done first, but you
>   can't say `<$foo>`  because that's an
>   indirect filehandle as explained in
>   the previous paragraph. (In older
>   versions of Perl, programmers would
>   insert curly brackets to force
>   interpretation as a filename glob:
>   `<${foo}>` . These days, **it's considered
>   cleaner to call the internal function
>   directly as `glob($foo)`, which is
>   probably the right way to have done it
>   in the first place.**)

I mostly use [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) and its ilk myself.

Comment: Your bold text is just an assertion: "considered cleaner" by who, in what cases?  The other text mentions a potential ambiguity with `<$foo>` that I have never run into as a problem in real code.  Is this note stating that the form is only an issue where the ambiguity occurs or does it apply to all uses of glob?

Comment: File::Find is pretty heavy duty when a glob is all you need. But, it sure beats writing your own recursive directory walking code.  You say and it's ilk, what other specific modules did you have in mind?

Comment: @daotoad: "Considered cleaner" at least by Larry Wall (as of Perl 5.002 beta 1, with "These days" being around 1995-11-21), according to the git history of `perlop.pod`. (And by me, for whatever that's worth.)

Answer (score 2):

These days I stick with `glob`, because I find it to be more readable and newbie-friendly(*) as compared to using angle brackets.

(*) [`perldoc -f glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) works.