# Difference between two forms of Perl filename wildcard command

Tags: perl, wildcard

There are two forms of Perl filename wildcard command: `<>` and `glob`. But I found there is difference between the effect of these two forms:

I want to retrieve all the files with similar names, using following code:

```
my @files = <"rawdata/*_${term}_*.csv">;   #(1)
```

and another format:

```
my @files = glob "rawdata/*_${term}_*.csv";  #(2)
```

I expect to get the same result using these two codes. But there is difference: if the `$term` is a string without spaces (or to say, one word), then (2) works well, but (1) doesn't work; if the `$term` is a string with spaces (or to say, several words), then (1) works well, (2) doesn't work.

Is there any difference between these two expressions?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the comparative advantages of glob('foo*') over <foo*>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087981/what-are-the-comparative-advantages-of-globfoo-over-foo)

Comment: Good question, the difference (interpolation) is explained in the question above

Comment: @DVK But it seems not answering my question about the problem caused by spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<SomeStuff>` is equivalent to `glob "SomeStuff"` (apart from all the ambiguities with `<>` also being used for reading from file handles -- see `perldoc perlop` and look for `I/O Operators` there). Therefore your examples aren't equivalent. You should use

```
my @files = glob "\"rawdata/*_${term}_*.csv\"";  #(2)
```

instead.

However, as to why space in the pattern makes a difference: `perldoc -f glob` tells the story. The normal `glob` (and therefore `<>` which is implemented via `glob`) treat whitespace as a pattern separator. The documentation also mentions `File::Glob` and its function `bsd_glob` which does not treat spaces as pattern separators. Therefore consider using this instead:

```
use File::Glob ':glob';

my $term1  = "some stuff";
my @files1 = glob "dir/${term1}*";
my $term2  = "more";
my @files2 = glob "dir/${term2}*";

print join(' :: ', sort @files1), "\n", join(' :: ', sort @files2), "\n";
```

Possible output with some files I just created:

```
[0 mosu@tionne ~/tmp] ~/test/test1.pl
dir/some stuff is betther than other stuff.doc :: dir/some stuffy teachers.txt
dir/more beer.txt :: dir/more_is_less.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference here lies in the use of quotes. From the docs:

> Note that glob splits its arguments on whitespace and treats each segment as separate pattern.

Using angled brackets <> does not require quotes. Glob requires quotes. As such, the following are equivalent:

```
my @files = <rawdata/*_${term}_*.csv>;
my @files = glob "rawdata/*_${term}_*.csv";
```

They will both split the pattern if ${term} contains a space. When you introduce quotes to the <> form, it prevents this split from happening on ${term}'s with spaces, thus searching for a different pattern.