# What does <*> mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

In the code below, what exactly does the `<*>` command do?

```
my @usbHddFileList = <*>;
foreach $usbHddFile (@usbHddFileList)
{
    system("rm -f $curMountDir/$usbHddFile < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1");
}
```

Comment: See also [Difference between two forms of Perl filename wildcard command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115772/difference-between-two-forms-of-perl-filename-wildcard-command)

Comment: Aside: Using `system("rm ...")` to delete files is **extremely** bad form, and incurs security risks (think about a file with `$(rm -rf ~)` in its name). Use `unlink()` instead.

Comment: Re: `"perhaps the search engines don't like the special characters"`.. In google you can quote special characters for exampe [this google search](https://www.google.no/?gws_rd=ssl#q=perl+%22-x%22) does not find the file test operator unless you include the surronding quotes

Comment: @HåkonHægland Google discards most special characters, even if quoted (searching for `perl X` and `perl "-X"` gives the same results for me). [Search for the topic of this question](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+%22%3C*%3E%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), for example, or even `<>`, which appears countless times in perlop. [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3C*%3E+perl) is a good alternative (although perlop, perlvar, etc. are even better).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot wow I was not aware of that.. symbolhound seems to work great though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `<>` means `readline(ARGV)`
- `<IDENTIFIER>` means `readline(IDENTIFIER)`
- `<$IDENTIFIER>` means `readline($IDENTIFIER)`<sup>[1]</sup>
- `<...>` (anything else) means `glob(qq<...>)`

So `<*>` means `glob(qq<*>)` or `glob('*')`.

[`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) is used to generate a number of strings or file names from a pattern.

In list context, `<*>` aka `glob('*')` returns all the files in the current work directory other than those whose name starts with `.`.

---

1. Note that `<$$x>`, `<${$x}>` and `<$h{x}>` do not match this rule. These are all globs. Use a temporary variable or use `readline` instead of `<>` if you want to access file handles indirectly.

Answer (score 9):

It's a [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html). According to [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a
>   simple scalar variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or
>   typeglob reference, it is interpreted as a filename pattern to be
>   globbed, and either a list of filenames or the next filename in the
>   list is returned, depending on context. This distinction is determined
>   on syntactic grounds alone.

Comment: And in the OP's code specifically, it returns the names of all (non-dot) files in the current working directory and stores them in `@usbHddFileList`.